# Facebook Graph search by location doesnt return page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

when I perform this query:

search?q=fuckin&type=place&center=50.9305992,6.9384799&distance=1000&limit=2000&fields=id,name

i'd expect this page to be in the results:    686513714751273

Name: "Fuckin' Monday"

but its not. even if I leave the q= empty and put latitide/longitude right on the event with a radius of 2000 it doesn't find it. does it have to do with the "fuckin" and fb thinks its inappropriate? But then why does a direct query for the page ID work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Are you looking for the Facebook Page of a place ? Or for an actual Place object ?**

For me it works with a **Page** for type. (HTTP Encoded)

```
graph.facebook.com/search?q=fuckin%27%20monday&type=page&limit=2000&fields=id,name&center=50.9305992,6.9384799&distance=1000
```

OR (HTTP Encoded)

```
graph.facebook.com/search?q=fuckin&type=page&limit=2000&fields=id,name&center=50.9305992,6.9384799&distance=1000
```

So you should specify in the Type the object type, not the Facebook Page type. If that was your intention. (since your Question title indicates an actual page)

Output example :

```
{
"data": [
    {
      "id": "293987407372110",
      "name": "Fuckin' Monday Madrid"
    },
    {
      "id": "686513714751273",
      "name": "Fuckin' Monday Köln"
    },
    {
      "id": "159859830745544",
      "name": "Metal Fuckin' Mondays"
    },
    {
      "id": "137862186385028",
      "name": "Fuckin' Monday München"
    },
    {
      "id": "304288229704190",
      "name": "Fuckin' Monday Lille"
    },
    {
      "id": "275769749221137",
      "name": "Fuckin Mondays"
    },
    {
      "id": "608070615956303",
      "name": "Fuckin' Monday Berlin"
    },
    {
      "id": "340716655944732",
      "name": "Fuckin' Mondays"
    }
}
```

Note : If you are actually looking for a **place** my answer is invalid.

EDIT 1 : Now I modified according to your comments with **Event**

```
graph.facebook.com/search?q=fuckin' monday&type=event&limit=2000&center=50.9305992,6.9384799&distance=1000
```

Output is now

```
{
 "data": [
 {
  "name": "FUCKIN' MONDAY",
  "start_time": "2015-12-28T22:30:00+0100",
  "end_time": "2015-12-29T22:30:00+0100",
  "timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "id": "328336493920924"
},
{
  "name": "FUCKIN' MONDAY",
  "start_time": "2015-12-28T22:30:00+0100",
  "end_time": "2015-12-29T22:30:00+0100",
  "timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "location": "Citrus",
  "id": "266920333408256"
},
{
  "name": "FUCKIN' MONDAY",
  "start_time": "2015-12-28T22:30:00+0100",
  "end_time": "2015-12-29T22:30:00+0100",
  "timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "id": "218674224902426"
},
{
  "name": "Metal Fuckin' Monday at Beerland with Eukaryst, WOB, Id, and Cathexis!!",
  "start_time": "2015-09-07T21:00:00-0500",
  "timezone": "America/Chicago",
  "location": "Beerland, Texas",
  "id": "412093375666047"
},
{
  "name": "FUCKIN' MONDAY: VERSCHOLLEN IM HK!",
  "start_time": "2015-07-27T21:30:00+0200",
  "end_time": "2015-07-28T21:30:00+0200",
  "timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "location": "zum hinteren Kreuz // HK Ulm",
  "id": "147966178716108"
},
{
  "name": "★ ♥ FUCKIN' MONDAY INTERNATIONAL PARTY @ Independance Club!",
  "start_time": "2015-07-13T23:45:00+0200",
  "end_time": "2015-07-15T05:30:00+0200",
  "timezone": "Europe/Madrid",
  "location": "Fuckin' Monday Madrid",
  "id": "1413329865620567"
},
{
  "name": "★ ♥ FUCKIN' MONDAY INTERNATIONAL PARTY @ Independance Club!",
  "start_time": "2015-07-13T23:45:00+0200",
  "end_time": "2015-07-15T05:30:00+0200",
  "timezone": "Europe/Madrid",
  "location": "Fuckin' Monday Madrid",
  "id": "725461987568076"
},
{
  "name": "Fuckin' Monday",
  "start_time": "2015-07-13T22:30:00+0200",
  "end_time": "2015-07-16T22:30:00+0200",
  "timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "location": "Roonburg",
  "id": "310759625778698"
},
{
  "name": "FUCKIN' MONDAY - jeden Montag im Ruby!",
  "start_time": "2015-07-13T22:30:00+0200",
  "end_time": "2015-07-14T22:30:00+0200",
  "timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "id": "1546763038913578"
},
{
  "name": "FUCKIN' MONDAY - jeden Montag im Ruby!",
  "start_time": "2015-07-13T22:30:00+0200",
  "end_time": "2015-07-14T22:30:00+0200",
  "timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "id": "649921368488042"
},
{
  "name": "FUCKIN' MONDAY - jeden Montag im Ruby!",
  "start_time": "2015-07-13T22:30:00+0200",
  "end_time": "2015-07-14T22:30:00+0200",
  "timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "id": "394242367414488"
},
{
  "name": "FUCKIN' MONDAY - jeden Montag im Ruby!",
  "start_time": "2015-07-13T22:30:00+0200",
  "end_time": "2015-07-14T22:30:00+0200",
  "timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "location": "Ruby Dance Club",
  "id": "417152511783993"
},
{
  "name": "FUCKIN' MONDAY - jeden Montag im Ruby!",
  "start_time": "2015-07-13T22:30:00+0200",
  "end_time": "2015-07-14T22:30:00+0200",
  "timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "id": "502362173237762"
},
{
  "name": "✦ MEET & DANCE: Learn Salsa, Merengue, Bachata & International Get-Together ✦",
  "start_time": "2015-07-13T21:45:00+0200",
  "end_time": "2015-07-15T00:30:00+0200",
  "timezone": "Europe/Madrid",
  "location": "Fuckin' Monday Madrid",
  "id": "841707392549858"
},
{
  "name": "✦ MEET & DANCE: Learn Salsa, Merengue, Bachata & International Get-Together ✦",
  "start_time": "2015-07-13T21:45:00+0200",
  "end_time": "2015-07-15T00:15:00+0200",
  "timezone": "Europe/Madrid",
  "location": "Fuckin' Monday Madrid",
  "id": "219024774934814"
},
{
  "name": "FUCKIN' MONDAY: Fuckin' Exams Edition!",
  "start_time": "2015-07-13T21:30:00+0200",
  "end_time": "2015-07-14T21:30:00+0200",
  "timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "location": "zum hinteren Kreuz // HK Ulm",
  "id": "568944169809566"
},
{
  "name": "FUCKIN' MONDAY: Fuckin' Exams Edition!",
  "start_time": "2015-07-13T21:30:00+0200",
  "end_time": "2015-07-14T21:30:00+0200",
  "timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "location": "zum hinteren Kreuz // HK Ulm",
  "id": "1447770675474865"
},
{
  "name": "FUCKIN' MONDAY: VERSCHOLLEN IM HK!",
  "start_time": "2015-07-13T21:30:00+0200",
  "end_time": "2015-07-14T21:30:00+0200",
  "timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "location": "zum hinteren Kreuz // HK Ulm",
  "id": "543891975651073"
},
{
  "name": "FUCKIN' MONDAY: Fuckin' Exams Edition!",
  "start_time": "2015-07-13T21:30:00+0200",
  "end_time": "2015-07-14T21:30:00+0200",
  "timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "location": "zum hinteren Kreuz // HK Ulm",
 }
}
```

Seems that the locations are still ignored because I get it from across the world.

- a not so promising bug :

> https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/122501314556518/?search_id

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer. I just took the query from the FB API description and since it worked for me for most cases, I didn't notice a difference. My ultimate goal is fetching all public events of a city, so I created a search grid over a city and then looked for all places. Can I also do something like `type=place,page` ? because both can create an event i believe

Comment: okay i tried a bit, but now, it doesn't adhere to my location filter anymore. As you can see in your answer too, you have all sorts of stuff, for Berlin, Madrid etc. but I'm searching in Cologne. so the type="page" causes the location to be ignored

Comment: Why don't you use type, "event" + the spacial information + name ?

Comment: I tried sth and updated the answer (since its easier to paste a Json result). But it seems the location is still ignored since there are also timezones from usa.

Comment: Seems like the problem is still in the fact, that facebook looks differently at "places" and "pages" however I don't get how a page cannot be place too.. most clubs are places apparently or at least they show up in my data base..

Comment: A Page has one-to-many locations/places because a foodchain has often multiple shops, so therefore a page can not be exactly the same for a place, since one Page can be generic for multiple shops or clubs.

Comment: how would I go about getting the Events of a Page then if that Page doesn't also have a place? All I have is the geocoordinates of the city and my search grid which I use to find the places and then their events. I'll mark your answer as correct as it technically is (since the problem is the type of the thing i'm looking for. I'll post another question with regard to my crawling strategy. thanks for the help!